# ASP.Net: Gridview throws error 'fired event RowUpdating which wasn't handled'

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

I have a Gridview on an ASP page bound to an SQL table.  I've configured the Grid to allow Multiple updates by replacing the default Label Controls with TemplateFields using the approach described here:
[Bulk Updates to Rows Bound to a GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036(v=vs.140).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Everything was working fine, until I made a change to bind the Gridview query programmatically on page load (With the aim of making the Gridview display different data depending on the user currently viewing the page) as described here:
[Bind Gridview programmatically](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-GridView-using-SqlDataSource-Programmatically-from-code-in-ASPNet.aspx).
After making this change the page now throws the following error when the user makes changes and clicks the update button:

*The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowUpdating which wasn't handled.*

Also when I try to do a single row update I get this error:

*Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled.*

I have read many threads on similair problems but I can't seem to find a solution to my error. I don't know why dynamically binding the Gridview would cause an error in rowupdating. Appreciate any support to resolve this.  Thanks.

Here's the Code:

```
Public Class Input
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        gvbind()


    End If



End Sub

Public Sub gvbind()

    Dim SqlDataSource1 As New SqlDataSource()
    SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1"
    Me.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1)
    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [ID], [Project], [Description], [CAPEX], [Team] FROM [CAPEX]"
    'Add Conditional Statements to change view for users/Teams
    'SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [ID], [Project], [Description], [CAPEX] FROM [CAPEX] where [Team] = 'Team1'"

    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub


Private tableCopied As Boolean = False
Private originalDataTable As System.Data.DataTable

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If Not tableCopied Then
            originalDataTable = CType(e.Row.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Row.Table.Copy()
            ViewState("originalValuesDataTable") = originalDataTable
            tableCopied = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Up_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Up.Click
    originalDataTable = CType(ViewState("originalValuesDataTable"), System.Data.DataTable)

    For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If IsRowModified(r) Then GridView1.UpdateRow(r.RowIndex, False)
    Next

    ' Rebind the Grid to repopulate the original values table.
    tableCopied = False
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub



Protected Function IsRowModified(ByVal r As GridViewRow) As Boolean
    Dim currentID As Integer
    Dim currentProject As String
    Dim currentDescription As String
    Dim currentCAPEX As String

    currentID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(r.RowIndex).Value)

    currentProject = CType(r.FindControl("ProjectTextBox"), TextBox).Text
    currentDescription = CType(r.FindControl("DescriptionTextBox"), TextBox).Text
    currentCAPEX = CType(r.FindControl("CAPEXTextBox"), TextBox).Text

    Dim row As System.Data.DataRow = _
        originalDataTable.Select(String.Format("ID = {0}", currentID))(0)

    If Not currentProject.Equals(row("Project").ToString()) Then Return True
    If Not currentDescription.Equals(row("Description").ToString()) Then Return True
    If Not currentCAPEX.Equals(row("CAPEX").ToString()) Then Return True
    Return False
End Function
```

Here's the Markup:

```
    <%@ Page Title="Input" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeBehind="Input.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication5.Input" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server"  ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server"   ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Data Entry
</h2>
<p>
    Enter Inputs Here<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("Project") %>' 
        id="TextBox4"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;<asp:Table ID="Entry" runat="server">
    </asp:Table>
    <asp:Button ID="TestButton" runat="server" Text="Test" />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
       AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" datakeynames = "ID" Width="502px">

        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" readOnly = "true" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID"/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="Project">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Project") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ProjectTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="30" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("Project") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="150" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CAPEX" SortExpression="CAPEX">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CAPEX") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CAPEXTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="10" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("CAPEX") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Project], [Description], [CAPEX] FROM [CAPEX]" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [CAPEX] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [CAPEX] ([ID], [Project], [Description], [CAPEX], [Team]) VALUES (@ID, @Project, @Description, @CAPEX, @Team)" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [CAPEX] SET [Project] = @Project, [Description] = @Description, [CAPEX] = @CAPEX,[Team] = @Team WHERE [ID] = @ID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Project" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CAPEX" Type="Decimal" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Project" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CAPEX" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Team" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="Up" runat="server" Text="Up" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BorderWidth="1" BorderStyle="Solid">
    </asp:Table>
</p>
```

Comment: Something is causing `RowUpdating` and `RowEditing` to be fired, so you need to handle them in your code. Buttons with `CommandName="Update"` or `CommandName="Edit"` would do something like that. [the-gridview-fired-event-rowupdating-which-wasnt-handled-c-sharp-code-behi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016531/the-gridview-fired-event-rowupdating-which-wasnt-handled-c-sharp-code-behi?rq=1)

Comment: You can post not just the codebehind but the asp code too.

Comment: I changed the Button name from 'Update' to 'Up' specifically to avoid firing any inbuilt functions, but I still get the problem.

Comment: I Edited the post to add the asp code, aparently It hasn't displayed yet. I'm told that any edits  go in a queue and need to be approved first to be displayed.... in the meantime here's my Gridview part of the code           <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
           AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" datakeynames = "ID" Width="502px">
             <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" readOnly = "true" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID"/>

Comment: Do you still have you SQLDatasource in both the front and code behind? Surely you need only one if you're moving to the binding in the code behind?

Comment: You're right!  I removed the SQLDatasource from the asp as it was redundant.  However this doesn't resolve my main problem... I still get this...                                                                                                       'The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowUpdating which wasn't handled.

Answer (score 1):

You make a call in `Up_Click` to 'GridView1.UpdateRow()'

From the MSDN Docs:

> Calling this method also raises the RowUpdated and RowUpdating events.

So all you should need to do is provide empty handlers

Comment: Fnostro, You’re absolutely right.  It seems Gridview1.rowupdate is also firing events RowUpdated and Rowupdating.  Although I must admit I don’t fully grasp the logic why these events need to be explicitly handled if they are inbuilt functions of the Gridview class?  In any case I added the empty handlers as follows:                                               Protected Sub Gridview1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating

    End Sub

Comment: Protected Sub Gridview1_RowUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdatedEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdated

  End SubNow                                                                                   When I click the update button, I no longer get the Error message “fired event RowUpdating which wasn't handled.”  Hooray!  
However now the Gridview does not update with the new value(s) entered. If this makes sense, I’m suspecting the handlers I added maybe overriding the inbuilt updating procedure?  Any other Ideas why Its not updating now?

Comment: BTW I tried to give credit/vote for your answer as well as the very helpful answers received from the gentlemen below but apparently as a new member I don't yet have this privilege :(

Comment: no worries about the credit, but to answer your question about why the events fire, it's because you are using the UpdateRow function OF the gridview, which requires having an Update command in the datasource.  You could have bypassed it and "rolled your own" or if you wanted to spend the time learning how, you could have used the SqlDataSource control directly by populating the parameters and calling _it's_ update function.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to fnostro's answer about `GridView1.UpdateRow()` raising RowUpdated and RowUpdating, showing the edit button like you do:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
```

will generate a button with `CommandName="Edit"`. Clicking this button will raise the RowEditing event, which you also need to handle in your code.

And as a side note, since your "Update" button is *outside your GridView*, the `CommandName` property won't be responsible for automatically firing a GridView event. So not only will changing the `ID` from "Update" to "Up" not have any affect, but changing the `CommandName` wouldn't have either.

Comment: @jf Just to clarify, clicking `Edit` will raise the RowEditing event, throw the GridView into edit mode and alter the Command Field to show `Update`/`Cancel`.  Clicking `Update` will raise the `RowUpdating` and `RowUpdated` events, and just fyi - all CommandField clicks raise `RowCommand`

Comment: @fnostro - Correct, thank you. So once OP handles `RowEditing`, he'll run into the same error with `RowUpdating` and `RowUpdated` if the new "Update" command field button is clicked and neither of those events are handled.

Comment: Newbie's code seems to have have changed since yesterday, but if he's now implementing SqlDataSource2 and the Edit CommandField he no longer needs the "Up" <asp:Button> nor its associated code  IMO - Newbie should also set the DataSourceID to SqlDataSource2 and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that SqlDataSource1 definition in codebehind lacks the UpdateCommand definition. 
To be honest I always used the SqlDataSource2 approach, it'd be as easy as add `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"` and the markup would be:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames = "ID"
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Width="502px">
```

That way you can forget about if the gridview has to be bound in postbacks. Unless you place the gridview inside an UpdatePanel, I'd say it has to be bound, and then the `If Not IsPostBack Then` is incorrectly placed.

The code `<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("Project") %>' id="TextBox4"></asp:TextBox>` looks placed outside of a databound control.

Comment: A word about UpdatePanels.  Regardless of how you initialize an UpdatePanel any control that triggers a postback, inside or outside, full or partial, causes a _Full Page Lifecycle_.  This includes all the binding that auto-occurs due to databound controls having their DataSourceID Property filled in.  An update panel, when configure for partial updates, will only update, meaning transmit back to the browser, it's own contents.