# Gridview Edit not working after search

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is my event handler for search.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
    GridView1.DataSource = ObjectDataSourceSearch;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

When I click edit for the search results, I get this error:

```
The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled.
```

Please help me.

The markup is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="Orange" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="None" Height="16px" Width="1168px" ForeColor="Black"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" PageSize="20">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="white"  />
     <EmptyDataTemplate>
          <div>  
              No Data Available
         </div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate> 
    <Columns>

    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression  ="Name"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Source" HeaderText="Source" SortExpression="Source" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="JobStatus" HeaderText="JobStatus" SortExpression  ="JobStatus"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message" SortExpression  ="Message"  />                
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FollowUp" HeaderText="FollowUp" SortExpression="FollowUp" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FollowUp2" HeaderText="FollowUp2" SortExpression="FollowUp2" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The GridView ' ' fired event RowUpdating which wasn't handled. C# code behind asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016531/the-gridview-fired-event-rowupdating-which-wasnt-handled-c-sharp-code-behi)

Comment: This is different. I can update the gridview initially but when It comes to the search result, I can't edit that new table( the result from that search)

Comment: you need to show more code perhaps the markup..

Comment: I just updated, please take a look! TY in advance

Comment: I would suggest reading this it's pretty much the same thing except the example shows with a delete button http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView---Delete-Row-with-Confirmation.aspx you still are not showing all relevant code I don't think

Comment: I am quite confused about the default functionality of Gridview Edit. When the gridview loads the data, I can edit and update. When I search for particular entries, I bind the result to the Same Gridview but this time, it wont let me Edit( Shows above mentioned error)

Comment: You can take a look at my answer to the following post. You will see which event handlers need to be implemented to allow editing/updating of data records in a GridView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827111/asp-net-gridview-how-to-edit-and-delete-data-records/36828018#36828018.

Comment: Maybe switching from a datasource given by a `DataSourceID` (before search) to another one managed in code-behind (after search) makes things more complicated. Could you choose one of the two methods and use it in all cases?

Answer (score -1):

This error because you use prop "Row Editing " without any implementation in  cs file 
you either have to remove this function from gridview properties

or implement it's method in cs file

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
   {

}

Answer (score -2):

please you have to implement RowUpdating event in your code like

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
   {
 // Write here code for edit Rows 
   }
```